# merging dataframe pandas different way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have the following dataframes in pandas:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4], 'D': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]})
```

I would like to "merge" and obtain:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 6 | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | 2 | 10 |
| NA | NA | 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 7 | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | 3 | 12 |
| NA | NA | 3 | 13 |
| NA | NA | 3 | 14 |
| 4 | 8 | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | 4 | 15 |

I have no clue what to do, please help.

Comment: Can you explain the logic?

Comment: It like a merge, where the A column is one key and C is the other, however it should "merge" without "duplicate values on column A and B also I want to shift one row in columns C and D. If I'm not clear, please tell me.

Comment: You can use `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` but I'm not sure how this will behave with different numbers of rows. It looks like you've had some NA's interspersed in your output - if we knew more about the rules on where those should be, to fill the gaps/missing rows, that would help. Alternatively you could add in some `None`s to your starting `dict`/`list`s so they begin as matching right lengths

Comment: @Roberto not sure I got the "duplicate" part, there is none in your example (consider updating), but see if my approach below is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sort by A and C keeping the rows in their relative order, [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), create a temporary key with [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html), then [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
out = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
         .assign(key=lambda d: d['A'].fillna(d['C']))
         .sort_values(by='key', kind='stable',
                      ignore_index=True)
         .drop(columns='key') 
      )
```

Output:

```
      A    B    C     D
0   1.0  5.0  NaN   NaN
1   NaN  NaN  1.0   9.0
2   2.0  6.0  NaN   NaN
3   NaN  NaN  2.0  10.0
4   NaN  NaN  2.0  11.0
5   3.0  7.0  NaN   NaN
6   NaN  NaN  3.0  12.0
7   NaN  NaN  3.0  13.0
8   NaN  NaN  3.0  14.0
9   4.0  8.0  NaN   NaN
10  NaN  NaN  4.0  15.0
```